# Linear Programming: Objective function goodness if variable holds value above a given constant value

Tags: linear-programming

In a Linear Programming formulation, stating that a punishment is to be introduced in an objective minimization function if a variable $S$ holds a value above a given constant $K$ ($K = 35$ in the below example), is quite easy:

- Variable $M$ is included in (minimize) objective function such that $M\ge0$ and $S-M-35\le0$.

Exemplified explanation: If $S$ gets value $30$, then $M$ may be kept at $0$, so no punishment in objective function. However, if $S$ gets value $40$ in problem solution, $M$ is forced to at least $5$, and consequently a punishment of $5$ is included, just as desired.

But what if we want to include goodness in objective function if $S$ gets value above $35$? E.g. in the previous example, a value of $S$ equal to $30$ should (still) not influence the objective function. But a value of $S$ equal to $40$ should decrease the objective function cost with $5$.

I originally thought this "swap" from badness to goodness would be easy, but I worked on it for almost a full day without finding a solution...

Comment: X-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3407798/339790

Answer (score 5):

For anyone reading the post.  I have got the following answer:

"In other words, you want to maximize $\max\{S−35,0\}$. You cannot maximize a max or minimize a min in linear programming because these problems are nonconvex. You would need to introduce binary variables.

In the badness example, you are instead minimizing $\max\{S−35,0\}$. Both minimizing a max and maximizing a min are doable with linear programming."

Answer (score 2):

You can easily add $(S-35)\times N$ to your objective function where $N$ is a big constant number. It works in two ways in a minimization problem:

- If $S \ge 35$ then you will have punishment in your objective function.
- If $S \le 35$ then it will decrease the objective function by the magnitude of $N$.

*While in your approach*: when you don't want the effect of $S\le 35$ in the objective function you can do the following:

Define $p$ and $q$ as binary variables and add all the following constraints to the model ($B$ is a big positive constant number):
$$S\le 35 \times p + B\times q$$
$$S\ge 35 \times p - B\times p$$
$$p+q=1$$
$$M \ge -B\times q$$
$$M \le B\times q$$
$$M \le S-35+B\times p$$
$$M \ge S-35-B\times p$$
$p=1$ when $S\le35$ and $q=1$ when $S\ge35$. In each of these situation only two of the last four constraints will be active. When $p=1 \rightarrow M=0$ and when $q=1 \rightarrow M=S-35$. Now you can add $-M$ to your objective function.

Comment: Your suggestion to impose $M \ge 0$ and $M \ge S - 35$ and then put $-M$ in the minimization objective does not work.  There is nothing to prevent taking an arbitrarily large $M$.

Comment: I dont understand the proposed solution. If S < 35, I dont want any effect on the Objective function. If I'd include (S−35)×M and −M to Objective function, then a value of (for instance) S=33 will add -3M to Objective function. But the goal was to have no Objective function effect if S<35.

Comment: @BjørnSigurdBenestadJohansen, I mentioned that in my answer but you are right, it needs more details. I am editing my answer.

Comment: @BjørnSigurdBenestadJohansen, please check the edited answer, I hope it will work this time.

Comment: Hi Oguz Toragay,  Without having looked 100% through the details of your answer, it looks to me like you are on the right track.  (Altough I would perhaps assume that 1 (not 2) binary variable would be enough).

Anyway, for my problem, this gets a bit too complex and/or I get a bit worried about execution time, so I I think I will try to reformulate the original problem in order to avoid even more binary variables than those I already have... ;)

Using CBC, I currently am at about 30-120 seconds solutions time, and I need to be careful not to increase solution time further... :)